# sql query to select from and to date

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select PERIOD_NAME
    from gl_periods
    where :l_date_from between start_date and end_date
    and :l_date_to between start_date and end_date
```

This query is not working.
I need to select from date and to date between those two columns.And should display all period names between those two dates.
Help me with this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select PERIOD_NAME
    from gl_periods
where :l_date_from <= end_date
    and :l_date_to >= start_date
```